# I'm trying to get a carousel working in Nuxt 3 but all the slides are showing and additionally extra elements are being painted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, carousel, nuxtjs3

I'm fetching an array of reviews I want to display in a carousel element showing one slide at a time. I am trying to loop through and use the index of the array as the current slide.

My problem is that all the reviews are showing at the same time on the page even though in Vue Dev Tools the current slide and slide count values are correct.

In addition, In the elements panel in dev tools, there are extra elements for all of the slides.

I've been able to do this in Vue 3 but I can't in Nuxt 3.

I've added a screenshot of the Chrome Dev Tool Elements panel showing the additional HTML which is weird since it's not like that in the Vue Dev Tools but I can see the extra elements being painted because of the dashes on either side of the value in the `h5` with the `reviewerName`. I can't figure out what part of my code is causing it.

[Elements Panel in Chrome Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REV71.png)

In Vue Dev Tools I can see the `currentSlide` value changing correctly according to the delay and the `getSlideCount` value is correct on the `BaseCarousel` component.

[Vue Dev Tools BaseCarousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNnzw.gif)

Here are the components in the order of reviews list to the carousel to the slide and finally the individual review.

```
// ReviewsCarousel.vue

<script lang="ts" setup>
defineProps(["reviews"]);
</script>

<template>
  <div class="relative">
    <BaseCarousel>
      <template #slide="{ currentSlide }">
        <BaseSlide v-for="(review, index) in reviews" :key="index">
          <template #review v-show="currentSlide === index + 1">
            <ReviewItem :review="review" />
          </template>
        </BaseSlide>
      </template>
    </BaseCarousel>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here

```
// BaseCarousel.vue

<script setup>
const currentSlide = ref(1);
const getSlideCount = ref(null);
const autoPlayEnabled = ref(true);
const changeDelay = ref(30000);

// slide navigation
// next slide
const nextSlide = () => {
  if (currentSlide.value === getSlideCount.value) {
    currentSlide.value = 1;
    return;
  }
  currentSlide.value += 1;
};

// prev slide
const prevSlide = () => {
  if (currentSlide.value === 1) {
    currentSlide.value = getSlideCount.value;
    return;
  }
  currentSlide.value -= 1;
};

// autoplay
const autoPlay = () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    nextSlide();
  }, changeDelay.value);
};

if (autoPlayEnabled.value) {
  autoPlay();
}

onMounted(() => {
  getSlideCount.value = document.querySelectorAll(".slide").length;
});
</script>

<template>
  <div id="carousel">
    <slot name="slide" :currentSlide="currentSlide" />
    <!-- navigation -->
    <div class="z-50 w-full h-full flex">
      <div @click="prevSlide" class="flex grow cursor-pointer z-50 -mt-20">
        <font-awesome-icon
          class="h-14 w-14 text-3xl text-primary cursor-pointer"
          :icon="['fas', 'angle-left']"
        />
      </div>
      <div @click="nextSlide" class="flex grow cursor-pointer z-50 -mt-20 justify-end">
        <font-awesome-icon
          class="h-14 w-14 text-3xl text-primary cursor-pointer"
          :icon="['fas', 'angle-right']"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
// BaseSlide.vue

<template>
  <div class="slide">
    <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <slot name="review" />
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.fade-enter-from,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter-to,
.fade-leave-from {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

```
// ReviewItem.vue

<script setup>
defineProps(["review"]);
</script>

<template>
  <div
    class="text-light flex text-center justify-center backdrop-blur-sm backdrop-grayscale rounded-lg p-8 md:px-2"
  >
    <ul v-for="fields in review">
      <p class="text-2xl tracking-wider max-w-prose">
        {{ fields.reviewerComment }}
      </p>
      <div>
        <font-awesome-icon
          v-for="i in fields.rating"
          class="text-accent text-xl p-1"
          :icon="['fas', 'star']"
        />
      </div>
      <h5 class="text-xl tracking-wider">-&nbsp;{{ fields.reviewerName }}&nbsp;-</h5>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt3 supports ([Vue3-Carousel-Nuxt](https://nuxt.com/modules/vue3-carousel-nuxt)) module